# How do I compare the accuracy of two measurement devices when one of them is the reference?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, msa

I'm currently trying to compare the measurement accuracy of two devices. However, I am using one of the devices as a "gold standard" to say something about the accuracy of the other device.

The quantity I am trying to measure is the distance (depth) to a point in a scene (image). I am using a laser scanner which gives me $(x,y,z)$ coordinates for a point and I am using optical geometry to give me $(x,y,z)$ coordinates for the same point. My base (or reference) measurement is the laser scanner measurement. I am using this as a gold standard. I now have a corresponding measurement from the optical geometry based measurement system. I have corresponding measurements for 1000's of points. I average the error in the difference between these and get a mean error. This error, however, neglects the fact that the laser scanner too is a measurement system and has its own error. It comes with an accuracy of $\pm5\,mm$ for an object at $10\,m$ range. How do I incorporate this into an accuracy metric for the optical geometry based system?

Comment: @gung, it is possible that the other tags cover Measurement System Analysis, but there is nothing in their wikis to define that as being included in the tags: http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/measurement-error/info and http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/measurement/info.  In fact, it was from reading those tags and noticing that most MSA questions are tagged with `anova` or some form of linear model that it seemed appropriate to add a tag for studying the measurement error of the measurement system. Gage R&R seemed too specific, and the full name was too long for a tag.

Comment: Fair enough, @Tavrock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When measuring the accuracy of a measurement system you are always faced with the problem that you can't know the "truth" exactly and so have to compare to a standard.  As you say your estimate of the accuracy is off because you are unable to take into account the accuracy of the standard.  Hopefully you used the the method as a gold standard because it is highly accurate. If you take repeated measurements with the standard you could then get an estimate of its accuracy.  For the moment assume both instrument provide unbiased estimates.  Then MSE=variance and Var(X-Y) =Var(X)+ Var(Y)  where X is the new measurement and Y is the standard.  You have an estimate of Var(X-Y) which you have been using as a rough estimate for Var(X) now by repeated measurements or some other means you have an estimate of the variance of the standard.  Subtraction the estimate of Var(Y) from the estimate of Var(X-Y) and you will have your estimate of Var(X).

Comment: I see, so you are saying Var(X-Y) = $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} (X_i - Y_i)^2}{N}$ ? And that Var(X) = Var(X-Y) - Var(Y)?

Comment: Yes because I am assuming the random components of the two measurement system estimates are statistically independent and hence Cov(X,Y)=0.

Comment: OK, I get that, thanks. Maybe a related question I should be asking is that what is a good metric to use to comment on the accuracy of a measurement? Let's say I am measuring length. Let Y be the truth and X be the measurement. Var(X-Y) tells me the variability of my measurement about the mean. Does that mean that the E[X-Y] (expected value) should be close to zero. Intuitively, if it is non-zero, then it means that there is a bias to the measurement right? E[X] = E[X-Y] + E[Y] right?

Comment: @Mustafa  That would be yes.